# Does powerbank cause interference with radio waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation

Today I was charging my phone with a powerbank in my car while travelling and noticed dirty noise from FM radio then I turned it off and it went away. Is that because of the radiation? Is it harmful for us to use those devices on the go?